# How to get actioncolumn icon component?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, gridpanel

I'm searching two days and can't find how to get access to `actioncolumn` component (NOT html) on rowselect. I need to set event on icon click using [Saki's component communication technique](http://examples.extjs.eu/compcomm.html) ([source](http://examples.extjs.eu/compcomm.js)).
My column looks like:

[image]

I found a way how to show/hide buttons on change row selection (this code uses in `GridPanel`):

```
sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect: true,
        listeners: {
            beforerowselect: function(grid, rowIndex, record) {

                // 7 is the last cell index
                var cell = grid.grid.getView().getCell( rowIndex, 7 );
                //select icons in cell
                var icons = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-action-col-icon', cell);

                //for each DOM element
                Ext.each(icons, function(icon, index) {
                    currentIcon = Ext.get(icon);

                    //if not 1st button
                    if (index !== 0) {
                        //Delete class that hides. Class 'x-hidden' also works
                        currentIcon.removeClass('x-hide-display'); //show icon
                    }
                });
            },
            rowdeselect: function(grid, rowIndex, record) {

                // 7 is the last cell index
                var cell = grid.grid.getView().getCell( rowIndex, 7 );
                //select icons in cell
                var icons = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-action-col-icon', cell);

                //for each DOM element
                Ext.each(icons, function(icon, index) {
                    currentIcon = Ext.get(icon);

                    //if not 1st button
                    if (index !== 0) {
                        //Delete class that hides. Class 'x-hidden' also works
                        currentIcon.addClass('x-hide-display'); //show icon
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Ok. Next. I want to show another window on click (set click event). But I don't know how to get access from `Window`/`Viewport`:

```
//get items
this.loanGrid = this.items.itemAt(0);
this.documentsGridWindow = this.items.itemAt(2);

//add events
this.loanGrid.on ({
    scope: this,
    afterrender: function() {

        selModel = this.loanGrid.getSelectionModel();

        selModel.on({
            scope: this,
            rowselect: function (grid, rowIndex, keepExisting, record) {
                //HOW TO GET actioncolumn 2nd button here???

        }
    });

}
});
```

I also tried to set `id` to this icon on `beforerowselect`, but on `rowselect` this code `Ext.getCmp('icon-id')` returns `undefined`.
`up()` and `down()` functions not helps me too =(

HELP please! =)

p.s. Sad, but `Ext.ComponentQuery` works only from ExtJS 4.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you are using rowselect instead of cellclick or an event about click? I can proposte to use cellclick: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick

Comment: @MichaelLane Just because `cellclick` don't listen to keyboard events (up & down keys) but `rowselect` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I re-wrote some parts of my application.

First we need to add some options to `actioncolumn`:

```
dataIndex: 'action',
id: 'action',
```

Grid row buttons show/hide now is independent of `actioncolumn` move:

```
 /**
 * buildSelectionModel
 */
buildSelectionModel: function() {
    var sm = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect: true,
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            rowselect: function(grid, rowIndex, record) {
                this.toggleFirstButtonShowState(grid.grid, rowIndex);
            },
            rowdeselect: function(grid, rowIndex, record) {
                this.toggleFirstButtonShowState(grid.grid, rowIndex);
            }
        }
    });
    return sm;
},

/**
 * toggleFirstButtonShowState
 */
toggleFirstButtonShowState: function(grid, rowIndex) {

    //'action' is data index of
    var colIndex = this.getColumnIndexByDataIndex(grid, 'action');
    console.log(colIndex);

    // 7 is the last cell index
    var cell = grid.getView().getCell( rowIndex, colIndex);
    //select icons in cell
    var icons = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-action-col-icon', cell);

    //for each DOM element
    Ext.each(icons, function(icon, index) {
        currentIcon = Ext.get(icon);

        //if not 1st button
        if (index !== 0) {
            //Show/delete class that hides. Class 'x-hidden' also works
            currentIcon.toggleClass('x-hide-display'); //show/hide icon
        }

    });
},

getColumnIndexByDataIndex: function(grid, dataIndex) {
    //columns
    gridColumns = grid.getColumnModel().columns;

    for (var i = 0; i < gridColumns.length; i++) {
       if (gridColumns[i].dataIndex == dataIndex) {
            return i;
       }
    }
```

`Viewport` part:

```
//get selection model
selModel = this.loanGrid.getSelectionModel();

selModel.on({
    scope: this,
    rowselect: function (grid, rowIndex, keepExisting, record) {

        //get second icon in actioncolumn
        var icon = grid.grid.getColumnModel().getColumnById('action').items[1];

        //save context
        var self = this;

        //add handler by direct set
        icon.handler = function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            //open documents window
            self.documentsGridWindow.show();
        };
    }   
});
```

All works as expected!